# How do I raise a ValidationError (or do something similar) in views.py of my Django?

Tags: python, django, validation, forms

I'm using Django forms. I'm validating in the model layer:

```
def clean_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data['title']
    if len(title)  < 5:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Headline must be more than 5 characters.")
    return title
```

However, there are some things that I need to validate in the `views.py` .  For example...was the last time the user posted something more than a minute ago?

That kind of stuff requires request.user, which the models layer cannot get. So, I must validate in the views.py.  How do I do something in the views.py to do the exact thing as this?

```
raise forms.ValidationError("Headline must be more than 5 characters.")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like validating in the model layer (as in the django.db.models.Model. Do you mean the django.forms.Form/ModelForm layer? I guess so

Comment: I have a similar requirement for a different reason: there's a field that's only sometimes required, depending on the page, so the view needs to enforce it as it's tightly coupled to the page.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think gruszczy's answer is a good one, but if you're after generic validation involving variables that you think are only available in the view, here's an alternative: pass in the vars as arguments to the form and deal with them in the form's main clean() method.

The difference/advantage here is that your view stays simpler and all things related to the form content being acceptable happen in the form.

eg:

```
# IN YOUR VIEW 
# pass request.user as a keyword argument to the form
myform = MyForm(user=request.user)


# IN YOUR forms.py
# at the top:

from myapp.foo.bar import ok_to_post # some abstracted utility you write to rate-limit posting 

# and in your particular Form definition

class MyForm(forms.Form)

   ... your fields here ...

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.user = kwargs.pop('user')  # cache the user object you pass in
      super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # and carry on to init the form


   def clean(self):
      # test the rate limit by passing in the cached user object

      if not ok_to_post(self.user):  # use your throttling utility here
          raise forms.ValidationError("You cannot post more than once every x minutes")

      return self.cleaned_data  # never forget this! ;o)
```

Note that raising a generic `ValidationError` in the `clean()` method will put the error into `myform.non_field_errors` so you'll have to make sure that your template contains `{{form.non_field_errors}}` if you're manually displaying your form

Comment: Great solution. Is this a hack? I love it though, ty

Comment: No, I'd not call it a hack. It's just leveraging the Django Form classes more than the default/tutorial approach. I've used it plenty of places and (as long as you are aware of what pop() will do, in that it removes the keyword argument from kwargs, there's nothing to catch you out. If you don't want to remove it from kwargs, use get() instead.

Comment: Nice! By your solution, I could pass the request object on the form so I could check the text content of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 9):

You don't use `ValidationError` in views, as those exceptions as for forms. Rather, you should redirect the user to some other url, that will explain to him, that he cannot post again that soon. This is the proper way to handle this stuff. `ValidationError` should be raised inside a `Form` instance, when input data doesn't validate. This is not the case.

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but from a usability point of view it'd be even better to just add that message as a flash/django.contrib.messages message and *not* redirect to a new page, but just render the filled-out form again. That way, the user can wait, say, 50 seconds, and submit the data again, without having to retype it all

Answer (score 6):

You can use messages in views:

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.error(request, "Error!")
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Messages is a simple effective solution for a simple form error.

Comment: but how to apply messages when you in forms.py?