# Django Form Validation Based on Distant Related Model

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-forms

I am still pretty inexperienced with Django but I am stuck on this one issue. I was given an almost-finished project where parents could fill out assessments on their children and then researchers could collect and store this data using Django and Postgresql. There are several related models located in two different apps, which all relate to one other. An "instrument" (type of test) can have multiple studies which in turn can have multiple participants. I made a badly drawn image to describe what I mean.

There is one form, BackgroundForm, which collects demographic information (age, birth weight, etc). This data is then stored in the model, BackgroundInfo with the participant's administration ID. I am having issues making the form validation more flexible. Certain instruments (tests) are for specific ages and I am not sure how to get this information all the way to BackgroundForm validation since this is located several relationships away. Is there a way to enable form validation that validates depending on the attributes of a model located several relationships away?

[Map of Django site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chhds.png)

**cdi_forms/forms.py**

```
class BackgroundForm(BetterModelForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()
    sex = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other')), widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BackgroundForm, self).clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('age') == '':
            self.add_error('age', 'Please enter your child\'s DOB in the field above.')

    class Meta:
        model = BackgroundInfo
        exclude = ['administration']
```

**cdi_forms/models.py**

```
class BackgroundInfo(models.Model):
    administration = models.OneToOneField("researcher_UI.administration")
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Age (in months)")
    sex = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = (('M', "Male"), ('F', "Female"), ('O', "Other")))
```

**researcher_UI/models.py**

```
class administration(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey("study")
    subject_id = models.IntegerField()

class study(models.Model):
    researcher = models.ForeignKey("auth.user")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51)
    instrument = models.ForeignKey("instrument")

class instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51, primary_key=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 51, blank = True)
    min_age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Minimum age", null = True)
    max_age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Maximum age", null = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I did some more searching and I was able to find this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482392/how-do-i-raise-a-validationerror-or-do-something-similar-in-views-py-of-my-dja). Basically, I grabbed the arguments I wanted in views.py and passed them to my form.

**cdi_forms/views.py**

```
def background_info_form(request, hash_id):
    administration_instance = administration.objects.get(url_hash = hash_id) # Each test has it's own URL identifier
    min_age = administration_instance.study.instrument.min_age
    max_age = administration_instance.study.instrument.max_age
    ...
    background_form = BackgroundForm(request.POST, instance = background_instance, min_age = min_age, max_age = max_age)
```

**cdi_forms/forms.py**

```
class BackgroundForm(BetterModelForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.min_age = kwargs.pop('min_age', None)
        self.max_age = kwargs.pop('max_age', None)
        super(BackgroundForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        #Now I can compare my age field to self.min_age and self.max_age
```