# Django - failed registration, displaying reason back to user

Tags: python, django

I'm using the built in django user model, but having trouble feeding back to the user why their registration details are failing.

For example, not meeting the models password requirements, existing user etc.

I have...

```
# forms.py - so they supply their email address for verification
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("email",)

# views.py

def register(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(
            request, "users/register.html",
            {"form": CustomUserCreationForm}
        )

    elif request.method == "POST":

        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            user.is_valid = False
            user.save()

        else:
            messages.info(request, 'invalid registration details')
            return render(request, "users/register.html", {"form": CustomUserCreationForm})
```

How do I find out why `forms.if_valid()` fails, and pass it back to the user? At the moment, it just gives a generic message back, with no user feedback as to why it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You can reach [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482392/how-do-i-raise-a-validationerror-or-do-something-similar-in-views-py-of-my-dja) post. It will be help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `form.is_valid()` the instance of the form becomes really important if there are errors, because those errors exist on that instance. So you need to pass that back to the user in order to display the errors.

So to do this in your case, you'd change your view as follows

```
    def register(request):
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(
                request, "users/register.html",
                {"form": CustomUserCreationForm}
            )
    
        elif request.method == "POST":
    
            form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save(commit=False)
    
                user.is_valid = False
                user.save()

            else:
                messages.info(request, 'invalid registration details')
                return render(
                    request,
                    "users/register.html",
                    {"form": form}  # This still includes the errors instead of creating a new form
                )
```

And with that, you can then iterate over the errors in the template.

```html
    <form method="post" action="{{ request.get_full_path }}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
        {% endfor %}

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, amazing answer and very helpful :-)